# I have 2 business networks A and B, Participants of A want to Read an updated Asset of B. Is this scenario possible?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am curious to know on this, as this would make designing complex business networks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out with the Hyperledger Composer 'next' release ('next' / v0.18.0,  at the time of writing).

We have a tutorial that shows the functionality that can be used by a business network(A) to access an asset, participant, or transaction that is recorded in another business network (B).

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/invoke-composer-network